# Why can't I change a state value using setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently developing an application using React Native.

This trial app has a parent function component and a child class component.

I want to send a state value from the parent to the child using props.

even though I use `setState()`, the state value doesn't change...

how can I resolve my problem?

---

Here is the code:

**Parent**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

import Child from "../components/Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState("AAA");

  return (
    <View>
      <Child texts={texts} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { texts: props.texts };
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    const { texts } = this.props;

    this.setState({ texts: "BBB" });
    console.log("handleChange");
    console.log(texts);
  };

  render() {
    const { texts } = this.props;

    console.log("render");
    console.log(texts);

    return (
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          this.handleChange();
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```

---

node : 12.18.3

react native : 4.10.1

expo : 3.22.3

Comment: you aren't using your state value. on the `Button` you hardcode the title to be `ADD`. Maybe you should reference the state value? also are you wanting to set the state on the parent component or the child? a child `setState` call is local only to the child component for is own state. Also, when the child mounts it defines it state from props, your `handleChange` function should just reference local state if thats the pattern you are trying to go for.

Comment: @John Ruddell, I want to set the state on the parent component, and I want to change the state by the button on the child component.

Comment: @John Ruddell Thank you for your advice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to pass a callback function to the Child which will then set the state on the parent.

**Parent**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

import Child from "../components/Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState("AAA");

  return (
    <View>
      <Child setText={setTexts} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class Child extends React.Component {
    
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.setText(dataYouWantToAdd);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```

Comment: I could resolve my problem, Thank you so much for your support !!

Comment: Just `setText={setTexts}` would be enough, no need to wrap it in another function.

Comment: Oh, and the constructor is now unnecessary.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron, I see, thank you for your advice!!

Comment: Edited it, @EmileBergeron thank you for optimization

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a callback function to let the parent handle the change how it needs to. Just pass the data back to the parent in the callback. Try this if you still got error do let me know

parent

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

import Child from "../components/Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState("AAA");

  const handleText = (val)=>{
    setTexts(val)
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Child texts={texts} handleChange={(texts)=>handleText(texts)}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

child

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.handleChange(this.state.texts);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```